# css prevent increase parent height

Tags: html, css, sass

how can i prevent parent increase height in css??

this is my html structure:

```
  <div class="tab-box">
    <div class="tab-box__icon">
      <font-awesome-icon
        v-else-if="icon"
        :icon="['far', 'user']"
        class="tab-box__icon--font-awesome"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="tab-box__content">
      <div class="tab-box__content--title">{{ title }}</div>
      <div v-if="!isVisible" class="tab-box__content--subtitle">
        {{ subtitle }}
      </div>

      <!--  input  -->
      <input
        v-else
        :ref="refName"
        v-model="text"
        type="text"
        :placeholder="subtitle"
        class="tab-box__content--input"
      />
      <!--  /input  -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

i display *subtitle* or *input* based on `isVisible: false` data.

and finally this is the result:

[image: result preview]

and this is my style:

```
.tab-box {
  padding: calculate-rem(20px);
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;

  &__content {
    &--title {
      color: $color--primary;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    &--subtitle {
      color: #848484;
      @include font-size(14px);
      line-height: calculate-rem(17px);
    }

    &--input {
      border: 0;
      width: 100%;
      @include font-size(14px);
      line-height: calculate-rem(17px);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: `calculate-rem` is function that convert px to rem.

how can i fix input height (or line-height) problem???

this is demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mortezasabihi/u4Lgmbx6/1/)

Comment: Have you tried `max-height`

Comment: We could sure use a [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you out better. Make sure your subtitle and input elements have the same layout properties (`display`, check `height` in the computed values DevTools panel, etc).

Comment: @chriskirknielsen jsfiddle added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're changing the `<div>` to an `<input>` element it becomes [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content). So just make it a block by adding:

```
&--input {
    display: block;
}
```